# Клетка которая находится по ударом в шахматах

Tags: python

Проверка допустимого движения короля:

```
def black_king_move(board, yPos, xPos, yNew, xNew):
    if board[xPos][yPos] == 'empty':
        if board[xPos][yPos] in white_figures:
           if (abs(yPos-yNew))<= 1 and (abs(xPos-xNew))<= 1 :
               move = True
        else:
           move = False

    elif board[xPos][yPos] != 'empty' and board[xPos][yPos] not in black_figures:
        if (abs(yPos-yNew))<= 1 and (abs(xPos-xNew))<= 1:
            move = True
```

Как проверить бьёт ли другая фигура определённую клетку при:

1. взятии на проходе;
2. атаке на короля с последующим запретом хода для остальных фигур;
3. проверка всех клеток по которым движется конь при рокировке чтобы те
       не находились под ударом

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. В чём сложности? Известны ли правила? Просто по одному все правила перебирайте. К примеру, для рокировки 6 правил существует.

Comment: @jfs, трудности в том, что мой король не видит когда его атакуют, то есть другие фигуры никак не взаимодействуют друг с другом

Comment: и почему вы, к примеру, не можете все фигуры обойти?

Comment: Делаем "виртуальную" доску, на которой будем отмечать клетки, которые находятся "под боем". Проходим по всем фигурам на "реальной" доске, для каждой фигуры рассчитываем, куда она может шагнуть, отмечаем эти места на "виртуальной" доске. Это нужно будет проделывать отдельно для "белых" и "черных". Дальше уже исходя из полученных данных отвечаете на ваши вопросы самостоятельно)

Comment: @insolor, как эти клетки получить? Ведь я могу пока только сделать ход каждой фигурой по её правилам, разве что в массив все возможные ходы добавить?

Comment: @This4fun, да, делаете отдельный массив, и в нем отмечаете куда может попасть любая вражеская фигура.